# SelectPDF loses Acroform field data upon conversion to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, pdf, entity-framework-core

First I load a PDF form "template" from a local file. Then I populate it programmatically, convert it to a memory stream, then print. The form prints without the new data. The reason I convert to memory stream is because I want to be able to populate the from from a database query then print without saving locally for security purposes. If I load a form with data already in it then print it works fine. I can do this both manually as well as programmatically.

I have tried disconnecting the memory stream from the form before printing.

I have tried converting the for to a byte[], then to memorystream.
I have examined Stack Overflow and have come somewhat close but not quite like my issue.

I have contacted SelectPDF Support who have not responded in a few days.

Here is my code:

```
private void TestSearchReplace()
{
        try
        {
            // Print the winloss data to a PDF

            // Form template
            string file = @"C:\CodeBackups\WinLossWeb\WinLossWeb_SelectPDF\w-9.pdf";

            // load the pdf form manager
            PdfFormManager form = new PdfFormManager();
            form.Load(file);

            // fill some fields
            PdfFormFieldTextBox name = form.Fields["f1_1"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            name.Text = "This is my name";

            PdfFormFieldTextBox businessName = form.Fields["f1_2"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            businessName.Text = "This is my business name";

            PdfFormFieldCheckBox clasifIndividual = form.Fields["c1_1"] as PdfFormFieldCheckBox;
            clasifIndividual.Checked = true;

            PdfFormFieldTextBox address = form.Fields["f1_7"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            address.Text = "This is my address";

            PdfFormFieldTextBox city =                     form.Fields["f1_8"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            city.Text = "This is my city";

            PdfFormFieldTextBox employer1 = form.Fields["f1_14"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            employer1.Text = "XX";

            PdfFormFieldTextBox employer2 = form.Fields["f1_15"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            employer2.Text = "1234567";

            PdfFormFieldTextBox ssn1 = form.Fields["f1_11"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            ssn1.Text = "123";

            PdfFormFieldTextBox ssn2 = form.Fields["f1_12"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            ssn2.Text = "45";

            PdfFormFieldTextBox ssn3 = form.Fields["f1_13"] as PdfFormFieldTextBox;
            ssn3.Text = "6789";

            var streamPDF = new MemoryStream(form.Save());

            // form.Close();
            PrintPDF(streamPDF);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message + " In WinLossByPlayerID.TestSerachReplace");
        };
}

public void PrintPDF(MemoryStream docStream)
{
        // File to print
        //string file = @"C:\CodeBackups\WinLossWeb\WinLossWeb_SelectPDF\WinLoss_Test.pdf";

        // instantiate PDF printer class
        PdfPrinter printer = new PdfPrinter();

        printer.Load(docStream);

        // set event handlers for before/after printing of each page
        printer.BeforePagePrinting += Printer_BeforePagePrinting;
        printer.AfterPagePrinting += Printer_AfterPagePrinting;

        // set first page to be printed (default value 1)
        printer.StartPageNumber = 1;

        // set the last page to be printed 
        // (default value 0 - all pages are printed, starting with first page specified)
        printer.EndPageNumber = 0;

        // set color space
        printer.ColorSpace = PdfRasterizerColorSpace.RGB;

        // set silent printing
        printer.ShowPrintProgress = false;

        // the document name to display (for example, in a print status dialog box or printer queue) while printing the document
        printer.DocumentName = "winlossTEST_Document.pdf";

        // select printer
        printer.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Data Center";
        printer.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "WinlossPrintToPDF.pdf";

        // set page size (specify paper size name, width and height in points)
        printer.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 826, 1169);

        // set page orientation (default Portrait)
        printer.PageSettings.Landscape = false;

        // set margins
        printer.PageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // print PDF document
        printer.Print();
}

// this is called before each page printing
private static void Printer_BeforePagePrinting(object sender, PdfPrinterBeforePagePrintingEventArgs args)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Preparing to print page " + args.PageNumber + ": " + args.PageSize.Width + "x" + args.PageSize.Height);

        // cancel printing process before starting printing page 3
        if (args.PageNumber == 3)
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Canceled before printing page " + args.PageNumber);
        }
}

// this is call after each page printing
private static void Printer_AfterPagePrinting(object sender, PdfPrinterAfterPagePrintingEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printed page " + args.PageNumber);
}
```

Comment: For clarity, if I load an acroform from a file then print directly, without first converting it to a memory stream, the form field data are in the printout. Anytime I first convert a document to a memory stream, the print from the stream, the form field data are not present in the print out.

Comment: Oh, I should also point out that the Printer_BeforePagePrinting() and Printer_AfterPagePrinting() methods were copied from the samples on SelectPDF.com.

Comment: Thank you, KJ. Does saving to the MemoryStream satisfy the form save requirment? var streamPDF = new MemoryStream(pdfDocument.Save());

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, SelectPDF was never intended to work with AcroForms. Yes, it works, but loses some functionality.
Instead I created my "template" using a regular PDF with text fields that can be populated programmatically. This way the PDF can go straight to print w/out first begin persisted to the hard drive.

```
//form.Save();
var streamPDF = new MemoryStream(form.Save());
PrintPDF(streamPDF, PrinterName);
```